# Pointers and Dynamic Memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I have a function that returns a pointer to an array. I'm running it in a loop and `free()` seems to be giving me problems. I'm not sure where, but it appears that somewhere in the main loop the memory that I'm trying to free is being used. I'm using Xcode 3.2.1 in 10.6 | Debug | x86_64 build.

The program will run through the main loop one time; the second time it encounters the `free()` it gives me the following error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x100100180: incorrect checksum for freed object -
object was probably modified after being freed.
```

Can someone point out (no pun intended) what I'm doing wrong with pointers here?

Here is the program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int *partition;
    int lowerLimit;
    int upperLimit;

    // snip ... got lowerLimit and upperLimit from console arguments

    // this is the 'main loop':
    for (int i = lowerLimit; i <= upperLimit; i += 2) {
        partition = goldbachPartition(i);
        printOutput(partition[0], partition[1], i);
        free(partition); // I get problems on the second iteration here
    }

    return 0;
}


int *goldbachPartition(int x) {
    int solved = 0;
    int y, z;
    int *primes;
    int *result;

    result = intAlloc(2);

    primes = atkinsPrimes(x);

    for (int i = intCount(primes)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        y = primes[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            z = primes[j];
            if (z + y >= x) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (z + y == x) {
            solved = 1;
            result[0] = y;
            result[1] = z;
            break;
        } else if (y == z) {
            result[0] = 0;
            result[1] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(primes);

    return result;
}


int *atkinsPrimes(int limit) {
    int *primes;
    int *initialPrimes;
    int *filtered;
    int *results;
    int counter = 0;
    int sqrtLimit;
    int xLimit;
    int resultsSize;

    primes = intAlloc(limit+1);
    intFillArray(primes, limit+1, 0);

    sqrtLimit = floor(sqrt(limit));
    xLimit = floor(sqrt((limit+1) / 2));

    // these loops are part of the Atkins Sieve implementation
    for (int x = 1; x < xLimit; x++) {
        int xx = x*x;
        for (int y = 1; y < sqrtLimit; y++) {
            int yy = y*y;
            int n = 3*xx + yy;
            if (n <= limit && n % 12 == 7) {
                primes[n] = (primes[n] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
            }
            n += xx;
            if (n <= limit && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5)) {
                primes[n] = (primes[n] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
            }
            if (x > y) {
                n -= xx + 2*yy;
                if (n <= limit && n % 12 == 11) {
                    primes[n] = (primes[n] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int n = 5; n < limit; n++) {
        if (primes[n] == 1) {
            for (int k = n*n; k < limit; k += n*n) {
                primes[k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    initialPrimes = intAlloc(2);

    if (limit >= 2) {
        initialPrimes[counter++] = 2;
    }
    if (limit >= 3) {
        initialPrimes[counter++] = 3;
    }

    filtered = intFilterArrayKeys(primes, limit+1);
    results = intMergeArrays(initialPrimes, filtered, counter, trueCount(primes, limit+1));
    resultsSize = counter + trueCount(primes, limit+1);

    free(primes);
    free(initialPrimes);
    free(filtered);

    results[resultsSize] = 0;

    return results;
}

int trueCount(int *subject, int arraySize) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if (subject[i] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int intCount(int *subject) {
    // warning: expects 0 terminated array.
    int count = 0;

    while (*subject++ != 0) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}


void intFillArray(int *subject, int arraySize, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        subject[i] = value;
    }
}


int *intFilterArrayKeys(int *subject, int arraySize) {
    int *filtered;
    int count = 0;

    filtered = intAlloc(trueCount(subject, arraySize));
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if (subject[i] == 1) {
            filtered[count++] = i;
        }
    }

    return filtered;
}


int *intMergeArrays(int *subject1, int *subject2, int arraySize1, int arraySize2) {
    int *merge;
    int count = 0;

    merge = intAlloc(arraySize1 + arraySize2);

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize1; i++) {
        merge[count++] = subject1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize2; i++) {
        merge[count++] = subject2[i];
    }

    return merge;
}

int *intAlloc(int amount) {
    int *ptr;
    ptr = (int *)malloc(amount * sizeof(int));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error: NULL pointer\n");
    }
    return ptr;
}

void printOutput(int num1, int num2, int rep) {
    if (num1 == 0) {
        printf("%d: No solution\n", rep);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("%d = %d + %d\n", rep, num1, num2);
    }
}
```

Comment: We would need to see atkinsPrimes() and printOutput() too, at a minimum. I removed the `xcode` tag because your IDE is not relevant to a programming logic question; that tag is (presumably) for discussing how to make the IDE do things for you a certain way.

Comment: I'd like to see intAlloc() and printOutput() since those are the ones that play with the pointer you are free()'ing

Comment: Ok, I've added those functions to the source code there.

Comment: @Dekarrin. Did your original `intAlloc` return a pointer or not?  You are not supposed to correct the code in the question, otherwise the answers do not make any sense.

Comment: I know. My original intAlloc did return a pointer. The above is what my source looked like before I posted it on SO.

Comment: That's not even compilable. And even if you fix the compiling errors the code won't execute nothing becouse you are not initializing the variables that command the show: lowerLimit and upperLimit. Still, what values for those do you expect us to use for testing? All I get is *X:No solution*

Comment: I got some output using 4 and 6. No crash at all.

Answer (score 2):

Why is `intAlloc` not returning **int*** ?

```
int *intAlloc(int amount) {
    int *ptr;

    ptr = (int *)malloc(amount * sizeof(int));
    if(ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error: NULL pointer\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return ptr; //like this
}
```

**EDIT** (after your update):

On `atkinsPrimes()` where is filtered being **intAlloc()ed**?

```
int *atkinsPrimes(int limit) {
    int *primes;
    int *initialPrimes;
    int *filtered;
    int *results;
    int resultsSize;

    primes = intAlloc(limit+1);

    // ...

    initialPrimes = intAlloc(2);

    // ...

    resultsSize = counter + trueCount(primes, limit+1);

    free(primes);
    free(initialPrimes);
    free(filtered); // Where was it intAlloc()ed?

    results[resultsSize] = 0; // make the array 0-terminated to make it easier to work with

    return results;
}
```

**EDIT** (after your *N-th* update):

This is a compilable version of your code. It ran smooth on my machine, no crashes. Compiled with g++ (due to declarations of variables inside the *for* statement):

**g++ (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int *goldbachPartition(int x);
int *atkinsPrimes(int limit);
int trueCount(int *subject, int arraySize);
int intCount(int *subject) ;
void intFillArray(int *subject, int arraySize, int value);
int *intFilterArrayKeys(int *subject, int arraySize);
int *intAlloc(int amount);
void printOutput(int num1, int num2, int rep) ;
int *intMergeArrays(int *subject1, int *subject2, int arraySize1, int arraySize2);


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: ./program <lower> <upper>\n");
        return 0;
    }


    int *partition;
    int lowerLimit = atoi(argv[1]);
    int upperLimit = atoi(argv[2]);

    // snip ... got lowerLimit and upperLimit from console arguments

    // this is the 'main loop':
    for (int i = lowerLimit; i <= upperLimit; i += 2) {
        partition = goldbachPartition(i);
        printOutput(partition[0], partition[1], i);
        free(partition); // I get problems on the second iteration here
    }

    return 0;
}


int *goldbachPartition(int x) {
    int solved = 0;
    int y, z;
    int *primes;
    int *result;

    result = intAlloc(2);

    primes = atkinsPrimes(x);

    for (int i = intCount(primes)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        y = primes[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            z = primes[j];
            if (z + y >= x) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (z + y == x) {
            solved = 1;
            result[0] = y;
            result[1] = z;
            break;
        } else if (y == z) {
            result[0] = 0;
            result[1] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(primes);

    return result;
}


int *atkinsPrimes(int limit) {
    int *primes;
    int *initialPrimes;
    int *filtered;
    int *results;
    int counter = 0;
    int sqrtLimit;
    int xLimit;
    int resultsSize;

    primes = intAlloc(limit+1);
    intFillArray(primes, limit+1, 0);

    sqrtLimit = floor(sqrt(limit));
    xLimit = floor(sqrt((limit+1) / 2));

    for (int x = 1; x < xLimit; x++) {
        int xx = x*x;
        for (int y = 1; y < sqrtLimit; y++) {
            int yy = y*y;
            int n = 3*xx + yy;
            if (n <= limit && n % 12 == 7) {
                primes[n] = (primes[n] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
            }
            n += xx;
            if (n <= limit && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5)) {
                primes[n] = (primes[n] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
            }
            if (x > y) {
                n -= xx + 2*yy;
                if (n <= limit && n % 12 == 11) {
                    primes[n] = (primes[n] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int n = 5; n < limit; n++) {
        if (primes[n] == 1) {
            for (int k = n*n; k < limit; k += n*n) {
                primes[k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    initialPrimes = intAlloc(2);

    if (limit >= 2) {
        initialPrimes[counter++] = 2;
    }
    if (limit >= 3) {
        initialPrimes[counter++] = 3;
    }

    filtered = intFilterArrayKeys(primes, limit+1);
    results = intMergeArrays(initialPrimes, filtered, counter, trueCount(primes, limit+1));
    resultsSize = counter + trueCount(primes, limit+1);

    free(primes);
    free(initialPrimes);
    free(filtered);

    results[resultsSize] = 0;

    return results;
}

int trueCount(int *subject, int arraySize) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if (subject[i] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int intCount(int *subject) {
    // warning: expects 0 terminated array.
    int count = 0;

    while (*subject++ != 0) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}


void intFillArray(int *subject, int arraySize, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        subject[i] = value;
    }
}


int *intFilterArrayKeys(int *subject, int arraySize) {
    int *filtered;
    int count = 0;

    filtered = intAlloc(trueCount(subject, arraySize));
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if (subject[i] == 1) {
            filtered[count++] = i;
        }
    }

    return filtered;
}


int *intMergeArrays(int *subject1, int *subject2, int arraySize1, int arraySize2) {
    int *merge;
    int count = 0;

    merge = intAlloc(arraySize1 + arraySize2);

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize1; i++) {
        merge[count++] = subject1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize2; i++) {
        merge[count++] = subject2[i];
    }

    return merge;
}

int *intAlloc(int amount) {
    int *ptr;
    ptr = (int *)malloc(amount * sizeof(int));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error: NULL pointer\n");
    }
    return ptr;
}

void printOutput(int num1, int num2, int rep) {
    if (num1 == 0) {
        printf("%d: No solution\n", rep);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("%d = %d + %d\n", rep, num1, num2);
    }
}
```

Since you are still omitting some source, I can only imagine that the problem is hidden there.

**EDIT**: (my last update)

To assist your debugging, you should replace your main() function by the one below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int *primes = NULL;

    primes = atkinsPrimes(44); // Evil magic number

    free(primes);

    return 0;
}
```

Having a minimal example to reproduce the behavior you pointed out is much better then the whole thing. Have fun with **atkinsPrimes(44)**

Comment: ahahaha 57 seconds faster. +1

Comment: @Muggen That happens to me all the time. I guess it's my first on the other side of the coin, thank you.

Comment: yeah, just noticed that. My code does return ptr; I accidentally deleted it when I posted the code here.

Comment: @Dekarrin Updated answer. But you do understand that you can only free() a pointer after it was malloc()ed right?

Comment: @Dekarrin and as @Muggen has stated before, it's good practice to ALWAYS initialize memory pointers.

Comment: @karlphillip all those pointers pass through intAlloc(), however, they do so in other functions, whiched have been snipped. Should I post all the functions that have been snipped here that use intAlloc()?

Comment: yeah. tbh unless there is a reason not to, you shouldn't really hide code.

Comment: Indeed, it would help youself and spare us from pointing errors on your code that you know that are not there.

Comment: By the way, here is something you should try: comment all the logic of the application and leave only free() and intAlloc(). If the application compiles and still reproduces the error THEN you should paste it here. I bet you will find the error yourself if you try it.

Comment: I've gone through all the active code in the loop with breakpoints on every single step and analyzed all the variables... I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: In the end, we can't help you without looking at the source code.

Comment: well, the only part I've snipped now is the logic from the very beginning, which is absolutely guaranteed to not operate on any malloc()'d or intAlloc'd memory of any kind. It only works with argc and argv. All the rest of the code is there, but like @Muggen, I think you'll see why I was hesitant to post it all.

Comment: I ran your code with args 36 and 108. I'm still getting the same errors. Results look like this:

Running…
36 = 31 + 5
38 = 31 + 7
40 = 37 + 3
42 = 37 + 5
44 = 41 + 3
46 = 43 + 3
48 = 43 + 5
50 = 47 + 3
52 = 47 + 5
54 = 47 + 7
56 = 43 + 13
58 = 47 + 11
60 = 47 + 13
62 = 43 + 19
*** Same error here.

Comment: @Dekarrin There you go, 2:21am here. I'm going to bed. Good luck.